# I want to see the movement of the Sphere on the screen(OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to see the movement of the Sphere on the screen.
but, If you run the code, you will not be able to update the screen.
How do I change the code to show a change in the location of the phrase I created?

```
void display() {
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluLookAt(0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

  GLfloat diffuse1[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
  GLfloat ambient1[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
  GLfloat specular1[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
  GLfloat position1[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1.0 };
  GLfloat diffuse2[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1 };
  GLfloat ambient2[] = { 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1 };
  GLfloat specular2[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1 };
  GLfloat emission2[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
  GLfloat shine = 300;

  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient1);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse1);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, specular1);
  glPushMatrix();
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, ambient2);
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse2);
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, specular2);
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, emission2);
  glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, shine);
  glRotatef(mer_revolution, 0, 0, 1);
  glTranslatef(0, 0.8, 0);
  glRotatef(mer_rotate, 0, 0, 1);
  glutSolidSphere(1, 300, 300);
  glPopMatrix();
  glFlush();
  }

void main(int argc, char** argv) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
  glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
  glutCreateWindow("");
  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
  glutIdleFunc(move);
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in the code: `position` should be `position1`. Furhter the projection matrix is missing, so the sphere is not in clip space and not "visible". Please correct that, to make it a [Minimal, **Complete, and Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Move 'gL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT' at the top of the display.
The screen must be initialized when performing a function. Only then will the screen continue to change.